# Seaborn stripplot in logscale

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I am plotting boxplot in logscale using pyplot.boxplots and then I want to do swarmplot/strip plot on top of it using seaborn.
However the seaborn messes us the entire scale and plots very absurdly. Any idea how I can give custom position in seaborn?

```
att1= np.sort(np.unique(df1.att1))

w = 0.085
width = lambda p, w: 10 ** (np.log10(p) + w / 2.) - 10 ** (np.log10(p) - w / 2.)
custom_widths = width(freqns, w)


ax.boxplot([df1[df1.att1== xi].att2 for xi in att1], positions=att1,
           boxprops={'facecolor': 'none'}, medianprops={'color': 'black'}, patch_artist=True,
           widths=custom_widths)
ax.set_xscale("log")
fig.set_size_inches(10.5, 8)
means = [np.median(df1[df1.Frequency == xi].CapDensity) for xi in freqs]
plt.plot(freqns, means, '--k*', lw=1.2)
```

This is image w/o strip plot:
[image: This is image w/o strip plot]

```
sns.stripplot(x="Frequency", y="CapDensity",data=df1, edgecolor="black", linewidth=.3, jitter=0.1, zorder=0.5, ax=ax)
```

This is when I do strip plot on top of boxplot.

[image: This is when I do strip plot on top of boxplot]

Comment: set the scale at the end

Comment: `df1` is undefined

Comment: The code is just a part of entire script to give an idea of what and how I am plotting. I cannot share the data and I am too newbie to generate random data that matches the plot. I hope you understand. Thank you for your consideration

Comment: @PaulH If you set the logscale at the end, the xlims will be calculated in linear scale and be much too wide (or even impossible).  When the x-values are 1 and 100, the default xlims are `-3.95, 104.95`. When setting logscale first, the default padding works as hoped for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use `att1` as positions for the boxplots, while seaborn will always put a stripplot at internal positions `0,1,2,3,...`.  The easiest solution would be to also create the stripplot via matplotlib. (A swarmplot would be much more complicated to create.)

Supposing you have similar data as your previous question, such a plot could be created as:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.choice([1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 30, 50, 100], 500),
                   'y': np.random.normal(750, 20, 500)})

xvals = np.unique(df.x)
w = 0.085
width = lambda p, w: 10 ** (np.log10(p) + w / 2.) - 10 ** (np.log10(p) - w / 2.)
custom_widths = width(xvals, w)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.boxplot([df[df.x == xi].y for xi in xvals],
           positions=xvals, showfliers=False,
           boxprops={'facecolor': 'none'}, medianprops={'color': 'black'}, patch_artist=True,
           widths=custom_widths)
medians = [np.median(df[df.x == xi].y) for xi in xvals]
ax.plot(xvals, medians, '--k*', lw=2)
ax.set_xticks(xvals)
for xi, wi in zip(xvals, custom_widths):
    yis = df[df.x == xi].y
    ax.scatter(xi + np.random.uniform(-wi / 2, wi / 2, yis.size), yis)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Seems like seaborn has a long way to go to become dependable for publication grade plots